# Передача аргументов в скрипт Powershell из Python скрипта

Tags: python, powershell

У меня есть сценарий powershell:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://api.nike.com/buy/carts/v2/RU/NIKE/NIKECOM?modifiers=VALIDATELIMITS,VALIDATEAVAILABILITY" `
```

Дело в том, что я совершенно не понимаю в повершеловских кодах, поэтому без понятия, как принимать аргументы в Powershell из Python скрипта

Гуглить пытался, ничего полезного и понятного не нашел(

Comment: что передаёт Python в Powershell? где в вашем примере код который принимает от Python? `Invoke-WebRequest` - Получает контент с веб-страницы в Интернете.

Comment: Поверщел запускает питон иди питон повершел?

Comment: @Violet В том то и дело что нет кода который принимает от python, я без понятия как это написать, ничего нагуглить неудалось

Answer (score 1):

Для отправки данных из `PowerShell` в `Python` воспользуемся следующим кодом:

```
$e = get-winevent -FilterHashtable @{logname='security';id=4740} -MaxEvents 1
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://192.168.0.2:5555/test -Method POST -Body ($e.Properties[0].Value, $e.Properties[1].Value | ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType "application/json"
```

отправим информацию события 4740.192.168.0.2 адрес ПК на котором запущен скрипт `Python`.

на стороне `Python` используем `Flask` чтобы принять данные:

```
import flask
from flask import request

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    print(request.json)
    return 'yeah!', 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```